# Eloquent | Add a custom value to select

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have multiple tables, which all hold different transaction data, here is an example:

```
$q1 = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('transactions_vk')->where('user_id', $userid)->where('amount', '!=', '0')->where('payed', 'Yes')
->select('type', 'id', 'package', 'payed', 'amount', 'date_modified as date_added', 'payed as chargeid')->get(); 

$q2 = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('transactions_stripe')->where('user_id', $userid)->where('amount', '!=', '0')->where('payed', 'Yes')
->select('type', 'id', 'package', 'payed', 'amount', 'date_added', 'charge_id as chargeid')->get();

$total1 = $q1->merge($q2);
```

I query them all and merge them into one single result. While I query them I know which payment type they are, in my example q1 are all VK transcations and q2 are all stripe transactions.

Is there a way to add this info here?

Something like `payment_type: VK` for q1 and `payment_type: Stripe` for q2?

So the resulting array would have this info for each item, items would look like this then:

```
amount: 8999
chargeid: "pi_chargeid"
date_added: "2021-09-10 10:47:29"
id: 70
package: 31
payed: "Yes"
type: "credits"
payment_type: "VK"


amount: 2495
chargeid: "123456789"
date_added: "2016-09-19 17:15:43"
id: 70405
package: 11
payed: "No"
payment_type: "Stripe"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a little hack to add a column in the select similarly in how you'd do it in pure SQL:

```
$q1 = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('transactions_vk')->where('user_id', $userid)->where('amount', '!=', '0')->where('payed', 'Yes')
->select('type', 'id', 'package', 'payed', 'amount', 'date_modified as date_added', 'payed as chargeid', DB::raw("'VK' as 'payment_type'"))->get(); 

$q2 = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('transactions_stripe')->where('user_id', $userid)->where('amount', '!=', '0')->where('payed', 'Yes')
->select('type', 'id', 'package', 'payed', 'amount', 'date_added', 'charge_id as chargeid',DB::raw("'Stripe' as 'payment_type'"))->get();

$total1 = $q1->merge($q2);
```

Update: Your queries seem to be union compatible so you might save yourself a query by doing:

```
$q1 = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('transactions_vk')->where('user_id', $userid)->where('amount', '!=', '0')->where('payed', 'Yes')
->select('type', 'id', 'package', 'payed', 'amount', 'date_modified as date_added', 'payed as chargeid', DB::raw("'VK' as 'payment_type'")); 

$q2 = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('transactions_stripe')->where('user_id', $userid)->where('amount', '!=', '0')->where('payed', 'Yes')
->select('type', 'id', 'package', 'payed', 'amount', 'date_added', 'charge_id as chargeid',DB::raw("'Stripe' as 'payment_type'"));

$total1 = $q1->union($q2)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can write code like this.

```
$q1 = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('transactions_vk')->where('user_id', $userid)->where('amount', '!=', '0')->where('payed', 'Yes')
          ->select(DB::raw('"VK" AS payment_type, type, id, package, payed, amount, date_modified as date_added, payed as chargeid'))->get();
            
$q2 = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('transactions_stripe')->where('user_id', $userid)->where('amount', '!=', '0')->where('payed', 'Yes')
           ->select(DB::raw('"Stripe" AS payment_type, type, id, package, payed, amount, date_added, charge_id as chargeid'))->get();
            
$total1 = $q1->merge($q2);
```